# Naturality in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, philosophy

> **Question.** How can we formalize these intuitions about predicates on matrices?

Let $P$ denote a predicate on matrices, so that $P(A)$ is true for some choices of matrix $A$ and false for all others. Then as I understand it, $P$ is preserved under **equivalence** of matrices iff $P$ is induced by a "natural" predicate on linear transforms between vector spaces.

Now let $Q$ denote a predicate on square matrices. Then as I understand it:

- $Q$ is preserved under **similarity** of matrices iff $Q$ is induced by a "natural" predicate on endolinear transforms.
- $Q$ is preserved under **congruence** of matrices iff $Q$ is induced by a "natural" predicate on bilinear forms.

I'm not 100% sure these statements are actually correct, especially that last one.

Anyway, these are imprecise statements, owing mainly to the undefined use of the word "natural". How can we formalize them? There is a suggestion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234127/natural-isomorphism-in-linear-algebra) that "natural" in this context is correctly formalized by the concept of a "natural transformation," but the details aren't clear to me.

Comment: Well, as you say, "natural predicate" is an imprecise notion. If you define it the way you do, then it becomes a precise notion, but then what more is there to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set and $P \colon M_n(\mathbb{F}) \rightarrow S$ a function which is invariant under similarity - that is, $P(A^{-1} \cdot B \cdot A) = P(B)$ for all $B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ and $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{F})$. You can take $S = \mathbb{F}$ and $P = \det$ or $P = \mathrm{trace}$ or you can take $S = \{0,1\}$ and think of $P$ as a predicate.

Using $P$, you can define a **family** of functions $P_V \colon \mathrm{Hom}(V,V) \rightarrow S$, one for each vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$ of dimension $n$, by

$$ P_V(T) = P([T]^{B_V}_{B_V}) \tag{1} $$

where $[T]^{B_V}_{B_V} \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ is the matrix representing $T$ with respect to the basis $B_V$ (used for both the domain and range) and $B_V$ is some arbitrary basis.

Now, for $P_V$ to be well-defined, we need to check that this definition is independent of the basis we have chosen for $V$ and this follows immediately from the similarity invariance of $P$. This "checking" is done "pointwise", for each $V$ separately. However, if we look at the family $\{ P_V \}_{V}$, we see that this family (of predicates, or invariants) satisfies an additional property - $P_V$ and $P_W$ are not independent but satisfy some relations.

To state them, let me introduce some notation. Given a bijective linear map $\phi \colon V \rightarrow W$, let me denote by $\phi_{*} \colon \mathrm{Hom}(V,V)\rightarrow (W,W)$ the linear map defined by
$$ \phi_{*}(T) = \phi \circ T \circ \phi^{-1}. $$ 
This map is a linear isomorphism. Then, for **any** pair of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ and any invertible linear map $\phi \colon V \rightarrow V$ we have the following commutative diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Hom}(V,V) @>{P_V}>> S\\
@VV\phi_{*}V @VV\mathrm{id}V \\
\mathrm{Hom}(W,W) @>{P_W}>> S
\end{CD}$$

That is, 
$$P_W(\phi_{*}(T)) = P_W(\phi \circ T \circ \phi^{-1}) = P_V(T)$$
for all $T \in \mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ and all $\phi \colon V \rightarrow W$. This is the naturality property of the **collection** of functions $\{P_V\}_{V}$. In fact, since $\phi_{*}$ is an isomorphism and any two vector spaces of dimension $n$ are isomorphic, we see that this commutativity implies that $\phi_{V}$ is determined uniquely by its behaviour on a specific vector space $V$.

Given a linear map $T \colon \mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$ there is a unique matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ such that $T(x) = Ax$ and so we obtain a ("natural", without any choices) isomorphism from $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{F}^n,\mathbb{F}^n)$. Using this identification, we see that $P_{\mathbb{F}^n} = P$ and we have extended $P$ from being defined on $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{F}^n,\mathbb{F}^n)$ (which is "naturally" identified with $M_n(\mathbb{F})$) to be defined on all $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$, but in a very specific way which keeps the diagram above commutative.

How can we construct a family $P_V$ of functions that are not natural in the sense above? Well, take two different similarity-invariant functions on $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ (say $\det$ and $\mathrm{trace}$) and "define" $P_V$ by

$$ P_V = \begin{cases} P_1([T]_{B_V}^{B_V}) & \mbox{if } V = \mathbb{F}^n \\ 
P_2([T]_{B_V}^{B_V}) & \mbox{if } V \neq \mathbb{F}^n \end{cases} $$

Then $P_V$ will still be a well-defined family of predicates (this uses the similarity invariant of $P_i$) but it won't satisfy the naturality property.

---

The same discussion applies for bilinear forms and I leave it as an exercise to choose the neccesary categories, functors and modifications in order to make the discussion match the definition of [natural transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) in category theory. Using the definition above, your statements become precise theorems (or rather "observations").

Answer (score 0):

$Q$ is preserved under similarity of matrices if it is constant on each equivalence class of the equivalence relation "similarity". That is, if $X,Y$ are matrices and $Q$ is preserved under similarity, then $Q(X)$ is true if and only if $Q(Y)$ is true.

I don't really unerstand what you mean when you say that a predicate is "induced by a natural predicate on endolinear transforms".