# Snake Lemma: "natural" or "functorial"

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

There are some really good discussions of the meaning/ambiguity of the term "natural" [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56938/what-does-the-adjective-natural-actually-mean/56956) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34963/what-is-a-natural-isomorphism).

One thing I didn't quite get from those answers: when we say the Snake Lemma, for instance, is "natural", shouldn't we really say it is "functorial"? In other words, it doesn't just associate with each diagram a long exact sequence, it takes maps between diagrams to maps between long exact sequences?

Comment: Natural sometimes means functorial and sometimes means something involving natural transformations. It's unfortunate but that's how people use the term.

Comment: How I like to think of it is that 'naturality' is when an object mapping can be naturally extended (by an arrow mapping) to a functor. A natural transformation can be seen as a special case when the target category is an arrow category.